# Lambda can't decrypt image

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-ecr, amazon-kms

I am working in a multi aws account context.
I have Lambdas in account A,B,C and an ECR in account D. Lambdas pull image from account D.

There is a client managed KMS with a dedicated key that is used by the ECR in account D.
The KMS policy key allows ROLE used by lambda to do KMS operations.
Lambda roles in account A,B,C allow use of KMS.

When i try to run my lambdas i have the following response:

```
Lambda can't decrypt the container image because KMS access is denied. Check the function's KMS key settings. 
KMS Exception: AccessDeniedExceptionKMS Message: The ciphertext refers to acustomer master key that does not exist, 
does not exist in this region, or you are not allowed to access.
```

Here is my KMS key policy strategy
[image]

And following, here is my role used by the Lambda:

[image]

And finally my ECR using the key

[image]

I have followed this docs from aws : https://aws.amazon.com/fr/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-kmsaccessdeniedexception-errors/

but error messages discussed in this link are slighty differents